# How to specify what an application is allowed to access and what not?

Tags: permissions, security

Using Ubuntu 22.04: I have downloaded several applications such as Firefox, LibreOffice, Thunderbird, Gimp, Zoom, Teams, Visual Studio Code, FileZilla FTP, HTOP, and a few others.   Some as native using `sudo apt install` and some as `snap install`.

Is there a way of specifying what each of of these applications is allowed and not allowed to access, such as microphone, camera, home directory, internet access etc.?

For example, if I wanted to block zoom being able to access any of my `~/home/username/Documents` files, but allow zoom to access my microphone & camera.  On the other hand, allow firefox to access only `~/Desktop` for downloads but no other directories and no camera/microphone.

Another example, to forbid LibreOffice being able to access `~/Pictures`

Would the solution differ it these were native apt installs or snaps?

Say Visual Studio Code is available both in `apt install` and in `snap install`, which would be safer to run in terms of ensuring my privacy that Microsoft doesn't collect any data in secret, as most big tech companies do.

Thank you!!

Comment: This question seems far too broad to be answered in the AskUbuntu format, even before getting to the tinfoil-hat nonsense. If you discover proof, code or other *real* evidence that an application is stealing your data, please file a bug report with sufficient detail for a engineer on the Ubuntu Security Team to reproduce the issue in their test environment.

Comment: What made you so paranoid?  Your solution is very simple: disconnect from the internet and nobody can send anything to any company.  All data sent to companies currently is opt-in on Ubuntu. You need to consent to it. If Microsoft uses opt-out you opt-out. It is that simple. If you want to trace outgoing traffic: your router has an extensive log and will proof 100% any phone-home action from software.

Comment: Thank you for the comments.  Not being paranoid, but I suspect the big companies are always on the hunt for our data and habits.

Answer (score 1):

Most of these application have options, to restrict them from accessing certain  facilities of your device

For example in **Firefox** you could select:

```
Settings > Privacy & Security > Permissions
```

And customise your permissions,

If you can't find an option in an application you can change the permissions and ownership of a particular folder/file

For example if you want to restrict access to /home/username/Documents run the command:

**Warning: Executing this command will restrict all applications from accessing the particular folder, only root can access it**

```
sudo chown root /home/username/Documents
sudo chmod a= /home/username/Documents
sudo chmod u+rwx /home/username/Documents
```